# FlexNVM Data Corruption When Power Cuts Off During Data Write

Tags: c, embedded, eeprom, nxp-microcontroller

I am using the NXP S32K148 Microcontroller.

Imagine in the middle of writing data to the EEPROM (FlexNVM module), power suddenly cuts off exactly in the middle of data transmission.

Is there any way to detect the exact data that has been corrupted for this reason?

I am aware of BrownOut detection supported by the MCU, which lets me know if something goes wrong in the middle of a FlexNVM write.

I am also aware of using CRC or redundant bits to check on read, but I am looking for any lower-level action by the EEPROM emulator itself to recognize data corruption.

Comment: There is no such lower-level function, it is higher-level functionality you must implement yourself.  This is an X-Y problem.  You'd do better to ask how to implement power-fail safe NV storage, than to ask if the hardware will do it for you.  The answer is no, so you are no further forward.

Comment: This isn't possible I think. Even though some of these parts have hardware ECC, writes to eeprom are the "expected" values even if you get cut off halfways because of power outage. The standard way to deal with such situations in high integrity applications is to use 2 "mirror segments" where at least one is valid at all times. Then in case one gets corrupted, it can at least get restored.

Comment: Thanks. The FlexNVM supports a backup EEPROM sector that includes status data related to stored data. I could not find any detailed information about this in the user manual and should consult the NXP technical forum for more information.